# Python How to choose field for POST data when multiple fields have the same name

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am having problems writing a **POST** request using the *requests* python module.
There are 8 input fields with this html mark up:

```
<input class="form-control col-md-9" name="submission[value]" id="submission_value" type="text">
```

Each is in it's own unique div.  Example:

```
<div id="problem_7">
        <input class="form-control col-md-9" name="submission[value]" id="submission_value" type="text">
</div>
<div id="problem_8">
        <input class="form-control col-md-9" name="submission[value]" id="submission_value" type="text">
</div>
```

As there are 8 input boxes with an attribute name of "submission[value]", how can I specifically POST data to the one in #problem_8 ONLY?

DevTools shows this (after decoded) as what is sent in the POST data:

utf8=✓&_method=create&authenticity_token=0S9z6WoYNSggXFo/6HP99CZ67V4qn4+QGy8+l36BV24BlAxkCXDAedGHItuXpCDxs7sPtkA1jGUIgNaJMSaxMQ==&submission[id]=8&submission[value]=2222&commit=Submit

Below is how my POST data payload is currently set up:

```
payload = {
            "submission[value]": x,
            "authenticity_token":authenticity_token
        }
```

Comment: Each input element should be from 0 to 7:
name"submission[0]", the next will be name="submission[1]" and so on. try it

Comment: run page in browser and use DevTools in browser to see what data is send (as POST) from browser to server.

Comment: do you mean to change my POST payload?
payload = {
            "submission[7]": x,
            "authenticity_token":authenticity_token
        }
The number didnt work.

Comment: I added the devtools POST output above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the `submission[id]` field as well. You can see in your POST data that the following keys/values are sent:

utf8=✓&_method=create&authenticity_token=0S9z6WoYNSggXFo/6HP99CZ67V4qn4+QGy8+l36BV24BlAxkCXDAedGHItuXpCDxs7sPtkA1jGUIgNaJMSaxMQ==&submission[id]=8&submission[value]=2222&commit=Submit

- `utf8` = `✓`
- `_method` = `create`
- `authenticity_token` = `<some long token value not relevant>`
- `submission[id]` = `8`
- `submission[value]` = `2222`
- `commit` = `Submit`

You should aim to replicate this as closely as possible. Looking at the source it seems like `submission[id]` needs to be set to the integer value of the problem you want.

Comment: this makes the most sense, and i want it to be the answer, but it still wont work.  I recently found that there is a csrf-token in the meta element, but i can't seem to get the server to accept it, either through POST or in the headers.  There must be some type of protection at works here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  CSRF protections require you to send the authenticity tokens via POST payload and cookie.

```
session_requests = requests.session()
cookies = {
     "authenticity_token":authenticity_token,
     "csrf-token":csrf_token
    }
    result = session_requests.post(SUBMIT_URL, data=payload,cookies=cookies)
```